# JS function to print div - Doesn't work in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, printing

I am using the below function in order to print a target Div using JS. This works fine in all browsers apart from chrome. The console throws the error: PrintElem is undefined.

```
    function PrintElem(elem) {
        Popup($(elem).html());
    }

    function Popup(data) {
        var mywindow = window.open('', 'to_print', 'height=600,width=800');
        var html = '<html><head><title></title>' +
                   '</head><body onload="window.focus(); window.print(); window.close()">' +
                   data +
                   '</body></html>';
        mywindow.document.write(html);
        mywindow.document.close();
        return true;
    }
```

I have tried calling the function onclient click with the following:

```
PrintElement('[id$=divExport]');
PrintElement('divExport');
PrintElement('#divExport');
PrintElement('#ctl00_body_ucJobDetails_divExport');
PrintElement('ctl00_body_ucJobDetails_divExport');
```

It works in Firefox and incredibly in IE 9 and 11!

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Some jsfiddle sample would be nice!

Comment: By seeing this code I assume you will get PrintElement is undefined

Comment: I think `PrintElement` is a typo and is supposed to be `PrintElem`.

Comment: Any reason you're not simply using a print stylesheet for this ...? Would spare you the whole process of opening a new window in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function name is  `PrintElem()`. But you are calling it as `PrintElement()`. Apart from this I don't see any other problem..

And use this line.

`PrintElem('#divExport');`

Comment: If that's true please close this for being a typographical error.

Comment: Thanks for your replies...Sorry that was a typo! Yes I am indeed using PrintElem

Comment: @TAR is it because of this `mywindow.document.close();` what the purpose of this line?